# ionic2 http post not sending request to server and it works perfect in browsers with ionic serve

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am making a HTTP POST request with

```
{email: "abc@cba.com", password: ******}
```

in **`ionic2, angular2`** app.

**Problem** : This works perfectly fine when i run the code with 'ionic serve'. But when i install the apk in android phone with **`ionic run android --target=xdxddx`** am getting below errors.

1. In the console it shows POST request as error ( refer screenshot )
2. Http request header shows the warning 'Provisional headers are shown' ( refer screenshot )

[image: screenshot from chrome device inspector]

[image: screenshot from chrome device inspector]

**CODE:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Events, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Constants } from './constants';

@Injectable()
export class UserData {
  _favorites = [];
  HAS_LOGGED_IN = 'hasLoggedIn';
  HAS_SEEN_TUTORIAL = 'hasSeenTutorial';
  SESSION_OBJECT = 'loggedInSessionObject';
  constructor(
    public events: Events,
    public storage: Storage,
    private http: Http,
    public constants: Constants,
    public platform: Platform
  ) {

  }


  login(username:string, password:string): Observable<any> {
    var loginUrl = this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('ios') ? this.constants.BASE_URL + "/users/sessions" : "/users/sessions";
    console.log( loginUrl );
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type","application/json");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    var body: Object;
    body ={
          email: username,
          password: password
        } ;
    return this.http.post(loginUrl, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: headers })
          .map((res:Response) => {
            var sessionObject = res.json();
            if( sessionObject.code == 'SUCCESS' ){
              this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, true);
              this.storage.set(this.SESSION_OBJECT,sessionObject);
            }
            return sessionObject;
          }

          )
          .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  };
}
```

Comment: use the image button to set images in question ..

Answer (score 1):

According to me, It Says  Problem with your api **header access control**.
You need to **enable access-control-allow-origin** to Your API side according to your API platform or I can say you need to **enable cors** to your API side.

for ex:

If you are using php at your API end then you can enable it by using following :

```
<?php
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://admin.example.com');  //I have also tried the * wildcard and get the same response
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes I have enabled the cors and am using ROR. Still it is not working. The same API is used in Ionic v1 app and there it is working.   
I have also tried these things,   
1) cordova-white-list plug in is added correctly  
2) enabled cors  
3) added below line in config.xml  
`<allow-navigation href="*" />`  
  
**NOTE:** The request is not even reaching to server

Answer (score 1):

I got ride of this clueless problem, ionic2 would have logged the error in a better way to show actual error.

**Root cause of problem:** `Androidmanifest.xml` did not have permissions added

**Solution:** adding below line to `Androidmanifest.xml` resolved error for me

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`